# Finding Randomly Order Substring in String

Tags: c++, string, substring

For my first part of the question, We have given a long string of input and we have to count the occurrence for it. 
For eg.

```
Input = AXBHAAGHXAXBH
Find = AXBH
Output = 2
```

This can be achieved by using the `string.find("term")` loop. Eg.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   int occurrences = 0;
   std::string::size_type pos = 0;
   std::string inputz = "AXBHAAGHXAXBH";
   std::string target = "AXBH";
   while ((pos = inputz.find(target, pos )) != std::string::npos) {
          ++ occurrences;
          pos += target.length();
   }
   std::cout << occurrences << std::endl;

}
```

However, I am not sure how to do the second part where, it needs to take into account the random structure:
Random structure refers to any orientation of our find. Important note: The find occurrences are always grouped together but can have different structure.
I do not want to use cases because some sample find are too big eg. Find **AXBHNMB** would have too many cases to consider and would prefer a more general approach.

```
Eg. AXBH is find, then AXHB is also acceptable for the occurence
```

A proper example:

```
Input = AXBHAAGHXAXBH**ABHX**NBMN**AHBX**
Find = AXBH
Output = 4
```

Prefer if you please code it for the given example with link to explanation/explanation to any new function you use.

Comment: Are you asking how to find all the substring permutations inside a string?

Comment: Is the `input` and `find` contains only upper case letters?

Comment: @Ron permutation of substring group together. I have updated the question eg. If find is AXB then the input will always have them group together eg. AXBNMNNOBXANBMOAXB

Comment: @arsho Yes. The inputs are always uppercase

Comment: @Gengestu Thank You for the edit

Comment: `"AXBHAAGHXAXBH**ABHX**NBMN**AHBX**"` has 5 occurances of `"AXBH"` at position 0, 1, 9, 15, 27 right?

Comment: **AXBH**AAGHX**AXBH** **ABHX**NBMN**AHBX**
Thus, 4

Comment: It won't take XBHA as it already considered AXBH for position 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that checking all permutations would take a lot of time.  Fortunately we don't need to do that.  What we can do is store the string to find in a `std::map<char, int>`/`std::unordered_map<char, int>` and then grab sub strings from the string to search through, convert those into the same type of map and see if those maps are equal.  This lets use compare without caring about the order, it just makes sure we have the correct amount of each character.  So we would have something like

```
int main()
{
    std::string source = "AHAZHBCHZCAHAHZEHHAAZHBZBZHHAAZAAHHZBAAAAHHHHZZBEWWAAHHZ ";
    std::string string_to_find = "AAHHZ";
    int counter = 0;

    // build map of the characters to find
    std::unordered_map<char, int> to_find;
    for (auto e : string_to_find)
        ++to_find[e];

    // loop through the string, grabbing string_to_find chunks and comparing
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < source.size() - string_to_find.size();)
    {
        std::unordered_map<char, int> part;
        for (std::size_t j = i; j < string_to_find.size() + i; ++j)
            ++part[source[j]];

        if (to_find == part)
        {
            ++counter;
            i += string_to_find.size();
        }
        else
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }

    std::cout << counter;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I understand most of your approach.

Can you please explain the "build map of the characters to find" step wise?

Comment: @Slava AFAIK this is O(NM) where N and M are the size of each string.

Comment: I think adding condition `if( part[c] > to_find[c] ) break;` can significantly optimize it

Comment: @UtsoRoy `for (auto e : string_to_find)` loops through each character in `string_to_find`.  `++to_find[e]` says store that character in the map and increment the value of the int that character maps to.  when you do say `++to_find['a']` if `'a'` is not in the map then it puts it in the map and gives it a value of 1.  If `'a'` is already in the map then it just increments the value.

Comment: @Slava Maybe.  I'd have to profile it to see if the cost of the branch is worth it.

Comment: @Slava Actually, that would break `to_find` as it could add characters to it.  You'd need `if( part.count(c) > to_find.count(c]) ) break;`

Comment: @NathanOliver it depends on data of course, but it will be able to avoid to check whole string if first symbol is not in a target for example. Yes you are right, though it would not break logic, it wold just have empty elements

Comment: Actually it should be `if( ++part[source[j]] > to_find.count(source[j]) ) break;` :)  and `std::unordered_map` can be used as well

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried using your code to better understand it but it only gives answer when only string_to_find with its current orientation.  eg. AHAZHBCHZCAHAHZEHHAAZHBZBZHHAAZAAHHZBAAAAHHHHZZBEWWAAHHZ should have ouput as 6 but the program gives output of 1 when finding AAHHZ

Comment: @Slava I've added the `unordered_map` is that is a great improvement.  `if( ++part[source[j]] > to_find.count(source[j]) ) break;` is not going to work as `count` returns if the key exists, not the mapped value.  I'm thinking trying to think of something to short circuit the loop.

Comment: @UtsoRoy Can you give me what you are using for `source` and `string_to_find`?

Comment: Condition can be `auto f = to_find.find( c ); if( f == to_find.end() or ++part[c]>f->second) break;` plus you may want to skip check if break happened, for example make `part` empty as a flag

Comment: @Nathan

source: AHAZHBCHZCAHAHZEHHAAZHBZBZHHAAZAAHHZBAAAAHHHHZZBEWWAAHHZ

string_to_find: AAHHZ

Output should be 6
(AHAZH)BCHZC(AHAHZ)E(HHAAZ)HBZB(ZHHAA)(ZAAHH)ZBAAAAHHHHZZBEWW(AAHHZ)

Comment: Also according to latest OP comment `i` needs to be modified if match happened

Comment: @UtsoRoy There was a bug.  I wasn't adding `i` to the size in the nested for loop.  It works now although it returns 9 matches `HHAAZ` and `HAAZH`.  Working on fixing that as I see you are supposed to skip those..

Comment: @UtsoRoy It is fixed now.  There might be some more room for optimization but if does what you need acceptably then they aren't really needed,

Comment: @UtsoRoy No problem.  Glad to help.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using unordered_map library?

Comment: @UtsoRoy You could use a regular `std::map`

Comment: @NathanOliver I am trying to do it with using the only libraries of string and iosstream. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: My uni complier doesn't allow map/unordered map and I cannot move on to other parts if I cannot use my previous answer.

Comment: @UtsoRoy If you can't use a map then what you will need to do is take the substring and sort it.  The compare the two sorted strings: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/654826465e74083f

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach is to iterate over the given string and searching the target string.

In each chunk, we need to sort the portion and compare if it matches with the target string.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int occurrences = 0;
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    std::string inputz = "AXBHAAGHXAXBH**ABHX**NBMN**AHBX**";
    std::string target = "AXBH";
    std::sort(target.begin(), target.end());
    int inputz_length = inputz.length();
    int target_length = target.length();
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<=inputz_length-target_length; i++)
    {
        std::string sub = inputz.substr(i, target_length);
        std::sort(sub.begin(), sub.end());
        if (target.compare(sub) == 0)
        {
            std::cout << i<<"-->"<< target<<"-->" << sub << std::endl;
            occurrences++;
            i=i+target_length;
        }
    }
    std::cout << occurrences << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0-->ABHX-->ABHX
9-->ABHX-->ABHX
15-->ABHX-->ABHX
27-->ABHX-->ABHX
4
```

**Extra function:** Uses [`sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function from `algorithm` header file.

**Time complexity**: more than O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: If you like it, give upvote and accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to find a canonical representation for both the search string and a substring. Two fast approaches are possible.

1) Sort the substring.
2) Calculate a histogram of letters.

Option 2 can be calculated incrementally by incrementing histogram bins for the incoming letters and decrementing the bins for outgoing letters in the search window.

While updating the histogram bin, one can also check if this particular update toggles the overall matching:

```
// before adding the incoming letter
if (h[incoming] == target[incoming]) matches--;
else if (++h[incoming] == target[incoming]) matches++;
// before subtracting outgoing letter
if (h[outgoing] == target[outgoing]) matches--;
else if (--h[outgoing] == target[outgoing]) matches++; 

if (matches == number_of_unique_letters) occurences++;
```

Then the overall complexity becomes O(n).